# Parsing a URL String in Java

Tags: java, jsoup

In Java, how can I parse a Google URL String to retrieve the base URL?

For example, from:

```
https://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.yellowpagesgoesgreen.org/Concord-CA/Arthritis%2BSpecialists&sa=U&ei=RGbGU7TsIdORuATUx4GwCA&ved=0CDsQFjAH&usg=AFQjCNEE-p8ESL0Dxhknnhw1Tk9kpwvFGw.
```

to:

```
http://www.yellowpagesgoesgreen.org/Concord-CA/Arthritis+Specialists
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can use simple parsing methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you have asked question not sure if you will get this, try something like this which will just parse it as you want. Not been coding java for sometime might contain syntax errors and need some editting as per your requirement.

```
 public String findURL(String googleURL) 
 {
        String [] first = googleURL.split("url?q=");
        String[] final = method[1].split("sa=");
        url = final[0];
        url = url.replace("%2B", "+");
        return url
 }
```

Comment: once you get the URL-encoded target, you could just unescape it instead of replacing components manually. That way it would work with, say, `http://myurl.com?a-parameter=a-value&another=another` (where all those = ? & would need unescaping)

Answer (score 1):

I propose url-decoding after isolating the string:

```
public String unGoogle(String googled) {
    int start = googled.indexOf("url?q=");
    int end = googled.indexOf("&", start);
    return URLDecoder.decode(googled.substring(start, end));
}
```

You can add error-detection to avoid looking for `end` if `start` fails, to wrap the exception in something better.